# How could you disable apps from other users

Tags: permissions, appmenu

Been wondering how to disable apps from other users or just restrict it to administrator use only.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict access to administrator only,

```
sudo chmod o-x /path/to/executable
```

To restrict access to group, first create a group,

```
sudo groupadd myapps
```

Then change group ownership of the executable,

```
sudo chown :myapps /path/to/executable
```

Then finally, add your favorite users to this group,

```
sudo gpasswd -a <user-name> myapps
```

Please note that this procedure handles a normal situation where apps are installed from package manager in default location (**/usr/local/bin** or **/usr/bin**) and are owned by administrator (**root:root**).